# iOS Bluetooth App- Check Paired Devices

Tags: ios7, xamarin.ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I build an iOS Bluetooth Enable app which connects to the external device and after connecting it pairs with the device. Now, I want to check if the user already paired the device so that i will not show the pair alert message next time?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you can't, there is no means in the Core Bluetooth API to check pairedness. The pairing dialog is shown by iOS when needed.